# My column aligned string is shown correctly in the console. But if I want to show it in my Blazor razor page, column aligning is lost. Why?

Tags: c#, string, console-application, razor-pages

I have following code in a console app that is outputting column aligned strings:

```
 public void Browse_OPC_Servers
 {
    var client = new EasyDAClient();
    serverElements = client.BrowseServers(ip_address);           
    foreach (ServerElement serverElement in serverElements)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"ServerElements(\"{serverElement.ClsidString}\").ProgId: {serverElement.ProgId}");
    }
 }
```

If I run the console app manually I see in the console that the results are aligned to columns as expected.

If I trigger the console app with Process.Start from my Blazor server app,and show the standard output of the console app on my razor page, then column alignment is lost. Why?

Razor.cs code

```
Process_OPCDA = new Process                
{
  StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
  {
     FileName = MTX_OPC_DA_reader_path,
     Arguments = arguments,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     CreateNoWindow = true
  }
};
Process_OPCDA.Start();
string[] item_values = Process_OPCDA.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Split("\n").ToArray();
Process_OPCDA.WaitForExit();
```

Razor code

```
@for (int t = 0; t < item_values.Lenght; t++)
{
    <tr>
       <td>@item_values[t]</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Because HTML ignores consecutive whitespaces, and your browser probably won't use monospaced font to display text.

Comment: If you want to display columns of data in HTML, use multiple columns, not one column containing multiple values.